# Has a replicator ever been built?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Has something like a hardware replicator ever been built? Something akin to [von Neumann probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_spacecraft), only it doesn't have to be for space exploration?

When I say "replicator", in this context I mean a piece of hardware that can create more instances of itself.

If it has not been built, how might one go about it? At first, I was thinking that the first unit would contain a computer with a program telling it what raw materials in the environment to look for and use. But then I realized that this means the very first instance would need to have fine enough motor control to build a new machine with a new computer in it. That's seems awfully complex for a first instance of a replicator (after all, self-replicating molecules are much simpler).

So there seems to be an optimum somewhere in the middle between the following two: making the first replicator too simple may result in its lacking the ability to replicate, but if we make it too complex then it will be too hard for it replicate. But any approach that comes to mind to build this machine seems too hard for replication.

PS: Engineering noob so not sure how to tag this!

Comment: Afaik no, nothing like this has ever been built.

Comment: One might argue that a human being is a replicator in its own right...  As far as specific mechanical hardware, I am pretty confident that nothing like this exists at least not anywhere we can access...

Comment: Ok, thanks. FWIW, and depending on what you mean, I don't think humans are replicators. Their genes are. If you mean in the sense of replicating *other things*, as opposed to self-replication, then yes, I agree that humans are replicators.

Comment: The realm of fantasy unfortunately!

Comment: This wikipedia article is one link away from the one you linked to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_machine

Answer (score 1):

No, a true hardware self-replicator has never been built and we are still far from it. To do that we would need to achieve *production closure* (every component of the self-reproducing machine can be constructed by the machine itself) and *material closure* (the machine is able to collect from within its operating environment all of the raw materials required to build its offspring). An obvious problem is manufacturing electronics, which currently requires many materials and a long supply chain.

For an overview of the field you can check [Kinematic Self-Replicating Machines](http://www.molecularassembler.com/KSRM.htm) and the more recent "Rise of the Self-Replicators: Early Visions of Machines, AI and Robots That Can Reproduce and Evolve".

Nevertheless, we did manage to build self-replicating sofware patterns, for instance in game-of-life, see [here](https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2018/11/12/fully-self-directed-replication/).